# C# - Unable to change TextBlock text from particular method

Tags: c#, wpf

Alright, so I'm not sure if this is just a feature of the TextBlock control, but I'm trying to allow a user to change a path in a settings window, which will be displayed by a TextBlock (I need text wrapping) on the main window.

So, I pass control to the main window when the user clicks the Apply button:

```
    private void Apply(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        MW.SettingsApplied(this, Properties.Settings.Default.QuotesPath);
    }
```

Then, the SettingsApplied function in MainWindow looks like this:

```
    public void SettingsApplied(SettingsWindow win, string path)
    {
        win.Close();
        PathTextBlock.Text = path;
    }
```

Yet, the text in the text block remains unchanged, despite the window closing. I can, however change the text block text at runtime if I put `PathTextBlock.Text = "test"` just after InitializeComponent().

Any ideas?

Comment: You're not passing a string to the SettingsApplied method when you call it. Is this your real code?

Comment: Whoops, don't know why I put that. It's really this: `MW.SettingsApplied(this, Properties.Settings.Default.QuotesPath);`

Comment: Are you setting `PathTextBlock.Text` anywhere else in your code?  Maybe your change is getting overwritten somehow.

Comment: I would recommend using the MVVM pattern for WPF. So you would have a property PathTextBlock on your ViewModel, which could be updated more easily. Take a look at the caliburn micro framework

Comment: The most obvious answer is that the `Settings.Default.QuotesPath` property is not being set correctly before you call the `MainWindows.SettingsApplied()` method. But without a good code example it's hard to say for sure. You should use the debugger to check all of your expectations about what the code should do, and see which expectation(s) is(are) incorrect.

Comment: Well it was being set correctly, as even replacing it with just a flat string like "test" had no effect, but I've since scrapped the idea, since it was a minor feature causing a lot of trouble.